# How to autorefresh asp.net MVC webpage if condition is met in background

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I am working on having the following functionality for my mvc website. I want to have, for example 5 selected users voting on some question. When a user has voted, they will remain in a 'waiting' state until everyone has answered. Once those 5 users have answered, the page would autorefresh and I can populate the next question.

My basic thinking is that I need something like the following pseudocode to execute every so often (say 10 seconds) to check the status, possibly in jquery... then my controller can populate the next question.

```
while(condition not met) { } //wait
refresh()
```

Is there any simple way to fulfil this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is exactly correct.
Uusing jQuery.get on a timer to your method to call jQuery. 
Call into a url (route/controller) to see if voting has completed and examine the data in your resulting function that you set as a callback in your jQuery.get function. 
If your condition is true, then jQuery can call another method using jQuery.load() to get the results and update your div such as:

```
$('#question').load('/Voting/NextQuestion/10');
```

See the following for error handling when you call your jQuery methods
[jQuery Error Handling](http://www.maheshchari.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling/)

Comment: Good to confirm what I thought... now to try and implement. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [pokein](http://pokein.codeplex.com/), it should do the trick for you

Answer (score 2):

Might want to take a look at [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync) as well.